# i don't understand why isnt my canvas playing animation

Tags: android, animation, canvas, live-wallpaper

> i've asked bard(google ai) it keeps giving me these codes but it dosent do anything the square is frozen.im trying it on wallpaperservice canvas
>
> i want to know how can i (modify/animate) items of canvas that i've already drawn

```
    Rect rectangle = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rectangle, "left", 0f, 500f);
    animator.setDuration(2000);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    animator.start();
    }
    });
    
    animator.start();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you have to store on the bitmap buffer